# Incrementing hours and days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am building a report in SSRS.

In design mode it looks like this:

[image]

`tat2` are values 1 through 192 and appear on the report like this:

```
1
2
3
...
192
```

I would like to know if there's a way to instead do something like this:

```
DAY 1 12:00AM
DAY 1 1:00AM
DAY 1 2:00AM
...
DAY 7 9:00PM
...
DAY 8 12:00AM
```

In other words, I would like to turn the numbers 1 through 192 into hours and days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Date.AddHours() for this - just create a new Date that's the start of any year and use

```
Date.AddHours(Fields!YourNumericField.Value)
```

This way you get rolling hours - will you ever have more than 192? What's the maximum range, as this would roll-over at 365. You could just mix and match and do an expression though like:

```
=Math.Ceiling(Fields!YourNumericField.Value / 24) & SomeDate.AddHours(Fields!YourNumericField.Value)
```

Something like that

I don't have SSRS on this machine to test though :P

Edit:

Ok so to get the base date you can use new DateTime(year, month, day)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

So the expression

```
="DAY " & Math.Ceiling(Fields!tat2.Value / 24) & " " & format(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddHours(Fields!tat2.Value), "hh:mm tt")
```

This should give:

```
DAY 1 10:45 AM
```

Should work - if you want to change the format of the 10:00AM bit check this reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

"HH:mm" gives you 24 hour time + minutes e.g. 23:54

"hh:mm tt" is 12 hour e.g. 12:00 PM

Have a play

Comment: this looks awesome thanks so much! can you please tell me exactly where i can add these formulas?

Comment: If you right click on the cell, you should be able to 'edit expression' - you can type any expression in pretty much anywhere in SSRS. You can also use a lot of the .NET framework in SSRS - so creating a date uses System.DateTime VB syntax - I'll update my answer

Comment: this looks amazing im trying to implement it now thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry should be Math.Ceiling :) - it rounds a number up to the next int - so 1.05 becomes 2 etc

Comment: this is unbelievably brilliant thank you so much for your help

Comment: No probs did it actually work? I'd be surprised because I don't usually write code that works first time :D

Comment: how can i get in touch for future questions?? :)

Comment: Haha, just post it here, I'm always around, and SSRS is one of my 'interesting' tags

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in the underlying query - not sure about doing it in SSRS:

```
SELECT 
  Tat2 / 24 + 1 as Day, 
  CAST(Tat2 % 24 AS CHAR(2)) + ':00 ' +
    CASE WHEN Tat2 % 24 > 12 then 'PM' else 'AM' end as AMPM
FROM YourTable
```

This won't, of course, handle more than 365 days, because it doesn't months or years.

Comment: ken this is really great! worked like a charm!!! thanks so much! i'm still trying the other solution right now because i prefer an SSRS solution